# Woocommerce conditional tags for custom sidebar is twentyseventeen theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

I'm using twentyseventeen theme and Woocommerce and want to have a custom sidebar for my woo commerce pages rather than the default theme sidebar (sidebar-1) which will be used elsewhere on the site.

So in my child theme's functions.php I registered my custom sidebar (sidebar-6),  populated it with widgets and tried to call it with a woo commerce conditional tag in my child theme's sidebar.php

I'm new to conditional tags and despite following advice on various online sites, so far have not been able to get this to work.  I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction with this.

The original theme sidebar.php looks like this

```
if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
return;
}
?>

<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary" 
aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Blog Sidebar', 'twentyseventeen' ); 
?>">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
```

I have tried various combinations of code to try to make this work but so far have failed.  This is what I currently have and it results in no sidebar showing up on any pages.

```
if ( is_woocommerce() ) : {
return;
}
?>

<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary" 
aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Shop Sidebar', 'twentyseventeen' );    
?>">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-6' ); ?>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->


<?php else:
return;
}

?>
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary" 
aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Blog Sidebar','twentyseventeen');         
?>">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a mistake in the following condition:

```
if ( is_woocommerce() ) : {
return;
  }
```

basically above you are saying if it's Woocommerce pages return and do nothing.

here is the correct one:

```
if ( is_woocommerce() && is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-6' ) ) :?>
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary" 
aria-label="
    <?php esc_attr_e( 'Shop Sidebar', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
    <?php
    elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) :
        ?>
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary" 
aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Blog Sidebar', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @SusanNeil you are most welcome, i will be appreciated if you marked the answer  as  correct answer and arrow up :)

Comment: Hi again, I hope I didn't speak too soon..the sidebar is not working as it should. So it is being pull in to the shop pages but then behaves strangely.  Not showing the widgets that I have put in but pulling in something different.  Then when I try again, pulling in the correct widgets but later one, showing something else. Do you have any ideas what might be happening here?  Thanks

Comment: @SusanNeil  so the content are changing after or during the page load? Can u post  the link here to check ?

Comment: Seems to be solved!  I started with a clean install and built the site up again from scratch...this time leaving off Gutenberg and Woo Commerce block builder.  No idea if these were causing the problem or whether it was something else that had crept in. But all now working, so fingers crossed that will remain the case.  Thanks again @kasholo.